Running 3 functions serially each running when the previous function completes
I'm trying to run 3 functions serially having each function complete before the next one starts.   The below code works fine but I get three warnings on the try await [one, two, three] line:

No calls to throwing functions occur within try expression
No async operations occur within await expression
Expression of type [()] is unused.

Any suggestions on the proper way to code this and not get these warnings?
Task {
    let one: () = await func1()
    let two: ()  = await func2()
    let three: ()  = await func3()
    try await [one, two, three]
}

func func1() async { ... }
func func2() async { ... }
func func3() async { ... }


The functions essentially decode JSON data from separate external sources and then calculations are done on the results so its important each decoding happens before the next one starts.

These 3 functions are suspicious: if it's important that they run in a specific order, why is it that none of them take input, or return a result? Most people would expect to see something like let one = await func1(), let two = await func2(one), let three = await func3(two). That would make the dependency obvious, and impossible to get wrong.

It is simply:
Task {
    await func1()
    await func2()
    await func3()
}

That will run them consecutively. Just be wary of introducing additional unstructured concurrency (Task {…}) in those functions.

Can the three await lines be written as await [ func1(), func2(), func3() ] ? Is that functionally equivalent?

That adds additional overhead of building an array (or tuple, which is the other pattern). The idiomatic solution is to just await them one at a time. The time we use this array/tuple approach is when we are using async let and want to run them in parallel, and actually need the results of the array/tuple. To my eye, at least, it makes the code more confusing (and negligibly less efficient) to introduce it here.

@HangarRash That depends on the order sub-expressions are evaluated in. Swift does it from left-to-right AFAIK, but I don't think that's guaranteed anywhere. IMO this array also begs the question of why the author didn't run these in parallel (looks like an oversight). Writing them on consecutive lines more clearly expresses the intent that they must run serially.
